# Parsing xml with xmlns in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, linq, namespaces

I am trying to parse this xml string but it return null when it has the attribute 'xmlns'. When I remove the attribute or rename it it works fine. 
I need to read small bits of xml which I am getting from web requests but it seems to be that most of the xml are formatted with this attribute. I have tried to put the response in a string and still returning null.

I have also tried:

```
Dim df As XNamespace =xelement.Root.Namespace
```

but getting root is not a member of XElement.

```
Dim filename As String ="<Age xmlns=""http://newage/age/result"">15</Age>" 

 label2.Content = XMLparse("Age", filename)


Function XMLparse(ByVal strTAG As String, ByVal strXML As String) As String

    Dim xelement As XElement = XElement.Parse(strXML)
    Dim val As String     
    Dim df As XNamespace = "abc"
    val = ""
    Try
        Dim q = From el In xelement.DescendantsAndSelf(strTAG)
                Select el.Value

        For Each em In q
            val = val + "" + em.ToString() + ","
        Next em
        val = val.TrimEnd(CChar(","))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Error: Can't search for tag in XML"
    End Try
    Return val
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function XMLparse(ByVal strTAG As String, ByVal strXML As String) As String
    Dim xelement As XElement = XElement.Parse(strXML)
    Dim val As String     
    Dim df As XNamespace.Get("http://newage/age/result")

    val = ""
    Try
        Dim q = From el In xelement.DescendantsAndSelf(df + strTAG)
            Select el.Value

        For Each em In q
            val = val + "" + em.ToString() + ","
        Next em
        val = val.TrimEnd(CChar(","))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Error: Can't search for tag in XML"
    End Try
    Return val
End Function
```